# message headers lost in Kafka

Tags: php, laravel, apache-kafka, librdkafka

**Main question**: While everything works on my setup, I mean producing and consuming messages work with messages and keys, but `message headers` are not received on the consumer side, is there any specific configuration for allowing message headers on a Kafka cluster?

I'm using a [laravel kafka](https://github.com/mateusjunges/laravel-kafka) package, everything is working just fine, I have a producer and a consumer both with Laravel and the mentioned package, and for the Kafka I'm using [bitnami/kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka) docker image. and everything works just fine. I can produce messages on a topic and successfully receive them on the consumer side.

Yet, the weird thing is that on the consumer side the headers are not available. it's lost somehow but I can get the message itself and the key and everything else.

```
$message = new Message(
        body: [
            'name' => 'test',
        ],
        headers: [
            'anotherName' => 'test',
        ],
        key: '1'
    );

Kafka::publishOn($topic)->withMessage($message)
```

I have also tested other methods mentioned in the docs, such as `withHeaders()`, still not working.

**I'm suspicious that there is something wrong with my Kafka setup, is there any specific change needed to be applied on Kafka for having headers on the messages?**

Comment: What version of Kafka are you using? What does your consumer code look like? What other tools have you tried using to debug your message content?